# Derivative of $f(z)=az$ at infinity is $\frac{1}{a}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, dynamical-systems

I was going through a dynamical system lecture note and there it is said that the derivative of $f(z)=az$ at infinity is $\frac{1}{a}$, where $z\in \mathbb{C}_\infty$ i.e., Riemann sphere. Normally I would have thought it is $a$.

Could someone please explain why it is $\frac{1}{a}$, and why is the answer $a$ wrong?

Edit: The description in the lecture is:
let $h(z)=\frac{1}{z}$, then $h^{-1}(z)=\frac{1}{z}$. Now let $f_1(z)=h^{-1}\circ f\circ h(z)=\frac{1}{a}z$. Then $f_1(z)^\prime\mid_0=f(z)^\prime\mid_\infty=\frac{1}{a}$. It is the last relation $f_1(z)^\prime\mid_0=f(z)^\prime\mid_\infty=\frac{1}{a}$ which I don't get.
Can a function have more than one derivative at a point?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Unless $a = 0$, $f$ has a pole at infinity. That means the derivative at infinity doesn't exist. If you view $f$ as a holomorphic mapping $\widehat{\mathbb{C}} \to \widehat{\mathbb{C}}$ of Riemann surfaces, the derivative of $f$ in the standard charts $\psi(w) = \frac1w$ around $\infty$ is $\frac1a$, but that is not an intrinsic property of $f$. Choose different charts, and you get different derivatives.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks. You seem to know this well. Could you please explain what you mean by "have a pole"? Because as I know pole is when the denominator polynomial has a zero, but we have no denominator here. Also what you mean by "standard charts". I come from engineering so don't know much technicalities. Thanks again.

Comment: Unfortunately, it takes a lot of explaining if the background is missing. Are you familiar (or at least not entirely unacquainted) with manifolds?  When we want to make sense of the behaviour of $f$ around $\infty$, we must view it as a map between manifolds. Note that the derivative of $f$ isn't a well-defined concept then (it depends on the choice of coordinate charts) - but the differential is, and we can talk about the differential of $f$ at $\infty$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Unfortunately I don't know what a manifold is even though the words is familiar. And I don't know what a chart is either. Could you please recommend me a book to read these, something readable, not too complicated. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I would advise you first to track down their definition of "derivative of _ at infinity", because it's not something well-defined.

If $X$ is a one-dimensional complex manifold, $f : X \to X$ is meant to be iterated, and $z \in X$ is a fixpoint of $f$, then if you pick any chart $\phi : (U \subset X) \to (V \subset \Bbb C)$ for some open $U$ containing $z$, you see that the number $\frac {d(\phi \circ f \circ \phi^{-1})}{dx}  (\phi(z))$ doesn't depend on $\phi$ and tells you what happens if you iterate $f$ starting with a point near $z$. If its modulus is less than $1$ then $z$ is called an attractive fixpoint : applying $f$ will attract a point towards $z$ ; if it is greater than $1$, $z$ is called a repulsive fixpoint : it will do the opposite and send the point away from $z$. And the argument tells you by what angle it will turn around $z$ each time.

One of the chart giving complex coordinates near $\infty$ in the Riemann sphere is for example $h : X \setminus \{0\} \to \Bbb C$ given by $x \mapsto 1/x$ and $\infty \mapsto 0$. If you use this chart you are left having to do the calculation described in the lecture.

Comment: Thanks. Could you also please explain what do you mean by a "chart" and second, why is the derivative not "well defined", what do you mean by well defined?

Answer (score 1):

The map $z\mapsto az$ on the Riemann sphere in an infinitesimal neighborhood of the origin is an expansion with factor $a$, while in an infinitesimal neighborhood of the "opposite" point "$\infty$" it is an expansion by $1/a$ (i.e. a contraction by $a$). To formalize this, change the variable by means of $w=1/z$ and then consider what happens at $w=0$.